# Creating tables with 421 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a table 421 columns. I want to store it in the same table because I have to calculate the Euclidean distance from it so storing it in the same table might make it faster. My question is there any method to create the 421 columns without writing the syntax..create table mytable(id int,a1 int,a2 int..............a421 int). So is there anythingI can use to create the table with 421 columns or I need to write the whole syntax? I want my column names to be id,a1,a2,a3,a4......a421.

Comment: create a small script to do it for you with a `for` loop.  Though, if a table needs 421 columns, the table structure really isn't what it ought to be.

Comment: I know creating a table with 421 columns is not a good idea but I have to save the 421 attributes of 30,000+ images so is it better to save it column wise or row wise?

Comment: if data not for index,sort,search.....convert data to json and store in 1 colume

Comment: Each image has 421 attributes that you'd need in a query?

Comment: How wide those attributes are? Is it whole integer, tiny int, byte or just boolean? Are you trying to save space?

Comment: The datas are of 0.0060263 this type. Yes each image has 421 attributes for which I have to calculate the Euclidean distance with another 421 attributes. This process is done for all the 30,000 images.

Comment: So is there any method I can achieve this? I need a method which is fast.

Comment: What have you tried? Gimme teh codez questions are not really welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create query in php using loop.

```
<?php
    $qry = "create table test (id int";
    for($i=1 ; $i<=421 ; $i++)
           $qry = $qry . ", a" . $i . " int";
    $qry = $qry . ")";
?>
```

and then you can use this **$qry** for creating the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple script to generate the whole query for you.

In Javascript:

```
var str = "create table mytable(id int";
for(var i=1;i<=421;i++) str += ",a"+i+" int";
str+=");"

console.log(str);
```